# Not able to upload image from react Ant to Node.js server via GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, antd

I am trying to upload image from (react + Ant Design) client-side to (Node.js) server via GraphQL
but I am getting this error in the form server

> Could not create Operator:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'filename')

I have tested the mutation through Postman and it works correctly

[image]

This is the frontend code:

```
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<File[]>([]);

<Form.Item name={"files"} label="Image" valuePropName='fileList'
           getValueFromEvent={(event)=>{
              return event?.fileList
           }}>
         <Upload  accept="image/png, image/jpeg" maxCount={1}
              fileList={fileList as any}
              beforeUpload={(_, fileList) => {
                  setFileList(fileList);
                  return false;
              }}
              customRequest={(info)=>{
               setFileList([info?.file as File]) 
              }}
              showUploadList={false}
              listType="picture-card">
                <div>
                  <PlusOutlined />
                  <div style={{ marginTop: 8 }}>Upload image</div>
                  {fileList[0]?.name}
                </div>
          </Upload>
 </Form.Item>
```

The mutation takes 2 arguments (input data and file):

```
    type Mutation {
       createOperator(request: OperatorInput, file: Upload): Operator
    }
```

I'm passing the params to the mutation like this:

```
    const [mutation, { loading }] = useMutation<Response, Request>(CREATE_OPERATOR);
    const result = await mutation({ variables: { request, file } });
```

What I realized that via postman request the file will reach the server and it includes:

```
Upload {
 resolve: [Function (anonymous)],
 reject: [Function (anonymous)],
 promise: Promise {
  {
    fieldName: '0',
    filename: 'IMG_20230411_181040.jpg',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
  }
},
file: {
  fieldName: '0',
  filename: 'IMG_20230411_181040.jpg',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
 }
}
```

And this is correct, then I am using it to save the image in the Cloud.
But from the client-side am not getting this promise and the above attributes.

It just an object contains the following:

```
{
  uid: 'rc-upload-1690197951111-71',
  lastModified: 1688137614360,
  lastModifiedDate: '2023-06-30T15:06:54.360Z',
  name: 'IMG_20230411_181040.jpg',
  size: 13313470,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  percent: 0,
  originFileObj: { uid: 'rc-upload-1690197951111-71' }
}
```

I assume that my frontend code is not sending the file correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to enable the multipart request on the client-side in the index.js file by adding `link: createUploadLink()` instead of `link: new HttpLink`

I am using  [graphql-upload](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload#graphql-upload)  on server-side

See below:

```
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';

const option = {
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  credentials: "include"
}
 const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    link: createUploadLink(option),

    /*link: new HttpLink({
        uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
        credentials: "include"
    }),*/
});
```

For more details, see the [installation](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client#installation)  section of apollo-upload-client